# Как отправить emoji в telegram bot в питоне aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Пытаюсь отправить смайлик в тексте в телеграмм боте, использую aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"], state="*")
async def user_registration(message: Message):
    await message.answer(text="Выберите вашу роль.\ud83e\udde0", reply_markup=choise_role)
    await RegistrationStates.choice_of_role.set()
```

в строку `text="Выберите вашу роль.\ud83e\udde0"` я вставил код смайлика, полученный от emoji бота в телеграме, это не работает, как это исправить?
Выдает вот такую ошибку

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position
> 19-20: surrogates not allowed

Answer (score 3):

я думаю в вашем случае можно использовать библиотеку `emoji`. Можете установить её командой `pip install emoji`.

Код:

```
import emoji
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"], state="*")
async def user_registration(message: Message):
    await message.answer(text="Выберите вашу роль." + emoji.emojize(":brain:"), reply_markup=choise_role)
    await RegistrationStates.choice_of_role.set()
```

Answer (score 0):

В этом вам поможет модуль 'surrogates'

Для этого установите этот модуль:

```
$ pip3 install surrogates
```

Как использовать в коде:

```
import surrogates
surrogates.decode('\ud83e\udde0')
```

Можете записать это в переменную, и уже в таком виде вставить в строку